# Hartl Rails Tutorial: upcase-ing email address in user_test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upcase

I'm about halfway through the Rails tutorial (excellent, btw), and have a little question.  Is there a reason that this test uses `duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase` and not the more succinct `duplicate_user.email.upcase` ?

Here is the full test.

```
test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
end
```

As far as I can tell, the test performs correctly doing it either way.

Comment: Just like with any programming language there is more than one way to do things he could have just done `duplicate_user.email.upcase!` and it would have given the same result. He might have wanted to keep things congruent with the example of duplicating information from a given user rather than manipulating the object itself. This is just my thoughts on this.

Comment: No, that wouldn't have changed the email in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the tutorial but you seem to be asking why the test is not written as:

```
test "email addresses should be unique" do
  duplicate_user = @user.dup
  duplicate_user.email.upcase
  @user.save
  assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
end
```

In this case, the line `duplicate_user.email.upcase` will just return the upcased email. It will not affect the attribute on the object. The test still passes because the `duplicate_user` has the same email address as the original `@user`, satisfying the test spec that email addresses should be unique.

What the test is actually doing is verifying that the code recognises an upcased email to be the same as a downcased email. In such a case, the original line in the test has the effect of assigning to the `email` attribute of the `duplicate_user` an upcased version of the email address.